# this keyword is returning true/false instead of element object in react/ react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, event-handling

```
I recently started learning/coding in react and I need help in fixing a bug. 
I have 2 checkboxes on my application screen but those checkboxes should work like radio button which means when I check one checkbox, other checkbox should automatically uncheck. I tried using below options but its returning true/false instead of element object
```

```
      <View style={{ flexBasis: '50%' }}>
                  <PrimaryCheckBox
                    onPress={this.toggleForPrimaryCheckBox}
                    checkBoxValue='forPrimary'
                    checkBoxLabel='forPrimary'
                    checkBoxViewStyle={stylesheet.CheckboxViewStyle}
                    checkBoxTextStyle={stylesheet.CheckboxTextStyle}
                  />
                </View>
                <View style={{ flexBasis: '50%' }}>
                  <PrimaryCheckBox
                    onPress={() => this.toggleForDependentCheckBox.bind(this)}
                    checkBoxValue='forDependent'
                    checkBoxLabel='forDependent'
                    }
                    checkBoxViewStyle={
                      stylesheet.CheckboxViewStyle
                    }
                    checkBoxTextStyle={
                      stylesheet.CheckboxTextStyle
                    }
                  />
                </View>
```

Note: PrimaryCheckBox component is a custom component

I tried the below options and none worked

```
1. onPress={() => this.toggleForDependentCheckBox.bind(this)}
2. onPress={this.toggleForDependentCheckBox.bind("forDependent",e)} //threw error that e is not defined
3.  onPress={this.toggleForDependentCheckBox}
     public toggleForPrimaryCheckBox = (e: MouseEvent) => {
    console.log(e);  //returns true when checked and false when unchecked
    console.log(this) // returns class component 
}
```

Can someone please help what mistake I am doing?
I am trying to use single function for both elements so that based on selected element, I can uncheck other element and perform other logic

```
     <View style={{ flexBasis: '50%' }}>
                  <PrimaryCheckBox
                    onPress={this.togglePrimaryDependentCheckBox}
                    checkBoxValue='forPrimary'
                    checkBoxLabel='forPrimary'
                    checkBoxViewStyle={stylesheet.CheckboxViewStyle}
                    checkBoxTextStyle={stylesheet.CheckboxTextStyle}
                  />
                </View>
                <View style={{ flexBasis: '50%' }}>
                  <PrimaryCheckBox
                    onPress={this.togglePrimaryDependentCheckBox}
                    checkBoxValue='forDependent'
                    checkBoxLabel='forDependent'
                    }
                    checkBoxViewStyle={
                      stylesheet.CheckboxViewStyle
                    }
                    checkBoxTextStyle={
                      stylesheet.CheckboxTextStyle
                    }
                  />
                </View>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do function binding on both `PrimaryCheckBox` components:

```js
<View style={{ flexBasis: '50%' }}>
                  <PrimaryCheckBox
                    onPress={() => this.toggleForDependentCheckBox.bind(this)}
                    checkBoxValue='forPrimary'
                    checkBoxLabel='forPrimary'
                    checkBoxViewStyle={stylesheet.CheckboxViewStyle}
                    checkBoxTextStyle={stylesheet.CheckboxTextStyle}
                  />
                </View>
                <View style={{ flexBasis: '50%' }}>
                  <PrimaryCheckBox
                    onPress={() => this.toggleForDependentCheckBox.bind(this)}
                    checkBoxValue='forDependent'
                    checkBoxLabel='forDependent'
                    }
                    checkBoxViewStyle={
                      stylesheet.CheckboxViewStyle
                    }
                    checkBoxTextStyle={
                      stylesheet.CheckboxTextStyle
                    }
                  />
                </View>
```